# CSP issue when using XMLHttpRequest in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, csp

I'm using below code to do a sample REST callout from LWC

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();            
request.open("GET", "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees", true);
request.send();
request.onload = () => {
     console.log('response..!', request.response);
}
```

I have added this "https://dummy.restapiexample.com" URL to CSP Trusted Sites also.
But, I'm getting below error.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In LWC if you are trying to do a callout use `fetch` like this.

```
let endPoint = "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees";
fetch(endPoint, {
  method: "GET"
})
  .then((response) => response.json()) 
  /* response.json() gives us back a promise
  we need to process the promise in .then()*/
  .then((repos) => {
    this.repos = repos;
  });
```

and add your url to CSP trusted sites:

[image]

Check [this](https://medium.com/salesforce-champion/todays-world-we-are-connected-to-each-other-and-it-is-very-important-to-share-the-data-between-93b6e0760fde) for example.

Comment: It worked. But, will all browsers support "fetch" method?

Comment: For compatibility check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API